# Add Date and Time to output text file

Tags: sql, file, text, output, wamp

I want to add date and time for output text file.

For example OrderData1506241249, how can I do it? 
I am using wamp and mysql workbench to do this. Please help.

```
$sql4 = "
    SELECT * FROM FOrder
    INTO OUTFILE 'OrderData.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Do you mean the current date and time the file was generated?

Answer (score 0):

To add it as a column, just alter your query to include the now() function:

```
SELECT *, now() as [Current Date] FROM FOrder
```

If you want it to show above or below the data just once, you could always do a union all. Suppose MyTable has 2 fields, id int and name varchar

```
$sql4 = "
    SELECT * FROM FOrder
    UNION ALL SELECT 0, 'Report Date: '+cast(now() as char) as [name]
    INTO OUTFILE 'OrderData.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is you want to add the date and time to the filename that the export is going to be put into.

So try this

```
$datetime = date('ymdHi');
$sql4 = "
    SELECT * FROM FOrder
    INTO OUTFILE 'OrderData$datetime.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

Comment: Well can you mark the answer as correct please for the benefit of others seeking similiar advice